# Redirect to another page using user input from user in prompt

Tags: javascript, prompt

I have prompt, and I want it so that when a person enters in something, for example - I ask: What is you namn? And the person responds John. Then I want it to appear on my other html page that says Hello John, with innerhtml. So it's not a popup but actually on the other page

But I can't seem to take the input the user writes in to my new page

Comment: The value persons type _John_ will not appear on second page. Until you store it somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with [cookies](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp).

Comment: @LowerClassOverflowian In general, I avoid link-only answers. However, I happen to know this site, and their links do not change. In addition, the site gives a much better answer than I could create.

Comment: @PlasmaPower: What we mean is that you can keep the link just fine, but also paste the relevant code here. StackOverflow is meant to be completely self-contained. The link is there for attribution to the original source.

Answer (score 0):

Link to the page with a parameter in the URL

eg. www.mywebsite.com?name=John

Then access the param on the new page with window.location.query

Comment: This is one option, but the user experience might be a bit weird. Who wants to see his name in a URL?

Comment: @isherwood Yea, I understand.. I use this method for email invites to allow someone to click a link in their email and have the field already filled out when then get to the signup page.

Answer (score 0):

I'd be inclined to pass the input to a hidden form field, then submit the form to the second page.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use JavaScript [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage) API?

Your current page:

```
var x = prompt('your name?');
if ( x ) {
    localStorage.setItem('person_name', x);
    // do redirection
}
```

On next page you can get your value with following:

```
var whatImage = localStorage.getItem('person_name');
```